# Построчная буферизация

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, помогите понять, что значит "построчная буферизация"?

Answer (score 1):

Это означает, что буферизация происходит до некоторого лимита (внутренний размер буфера), либо до конца строки. Теоретически может и только до конца строки (буфер может увеличиваться по мере необходимости), но на практике некий лимит внутри есть. Может быть как при вводе, так и при выводе.

Comment: Спасибо понятно

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из логики возможен термин "чересстрочная", есть такое в видео графике, когда работа с изображением (вывод/ввод/обработка/кодирование) осуществляется через строку пикселей (четные и нечетные), для экономии аппаратных и программных ресурсов. С ним работают форматы HD-1080i, HD-720i, PAL/SECAM, такого типа съемка ведется некоторыми телефонами и камерами.

Comment: Да, но какое это имеет отношение к C# ?

Comment: На C# написано очень много приложений, в то числе и для работы с видеоданными.